# get Custom Taxonomy Custom field in SQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have created custom field from [this example](https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/)

I would like to get taxonomies name by containing "web" in `custom_term_meta`(created new field) in mysql query in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 4.4 and up has Term Meta built in: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/

But in your example you are storing term meta in wp_options table. You should get the value via get_option() function like this:

```
echo get_option("taxonomy_$term_id");
```

... where the $term_id is the ID of the term for which you would like to get the meta data.